# PDF download fails showing message "Couldn't be downloaded" only in IE11

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, webforms

I use ASP.NET with web forms, something that should be really easy is driving me crazy, similar questions have been asked but none of them helped me, IE refuses to download my files.

Things to notice:

- I'm testing locally
- It works in Firefox and Chrome but not IE11
- IE changes file name to page's name (for example it tries to save default_aspx instead of myfile.pdf)
  [image: File name changed]
  [image]

This is my code:

```
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ContentType = "Application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
Response.End();
```

These are the headers I got from IE:

Key Value

Response    HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Cache-Control   private

Content-Type    Application/PDF

Server  Microsoft-IIS/7.5

Content-Disposition attachment; filename=myfile.pdf

X-AspNet-Version    4.0.30319

X-Powered-By    ASP.NET

Date    Fri, 10 Apr 2015 22:44:40 GMT

Content-Length  691892

**UPDATE**

It seems like this is a server configuration issue because the same code will work fine in my production server but not in my development server.
So my client won't complain about this, anyway I want to fix it in my development environment, as soon as I have time I'll investigate a little more, if I find a solution I'll post it here.

Comment: [IE 10 - File download issues](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655566/ie-10-file-download-issues), [“File couldn't be downloaded” in Internet Explorer with ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609837/file-couldnt-be-downloaded-in-internet-explorer-with-asp-net-mvc).

Comment: After downloading with Chrome, have you verified your content-length matches the actual size of your content?

Comment: Have you tried using IE from another machine? The issue might be caused by certain settings of the browser. I found an article about previous versions of IE with the same problem:  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2549423

Comment: Could you provide a little information about how and when your Response code is being invoked?  Is it an automatic response to a requested URL?  Is it on a button click event?

Comment: which exact version of IE are you using ??

Comment: did any body resolve this? below answers did not resolve this

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had a similar issue in ie8 the problem is that the file is searched in the cache and is not found. To test this please set Cache-Control : no-cache in your response object.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the exact answer but hope if it can open some ways to find the exact one.

While googling I found this may be due to a security update release by Microsoft for IE.

> Microsoft released a security
>   update for IE11 on 8 Jul 14 which has a bug affecting the download.

And here is the [**Microsoft Connect Link**](https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/921934/ie-hangs-when-form-is-submitted-with-file-and-server-responds-with-content-disposition-attachment-header) that mention this under **active** status.

Please share exact solution once you find it.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 2):

I do something similar in my own app. Try removing the `content-disposition` header and change `Application/pdf` to `application/pdf`.  You also likely don't need `Response.End()`, though I doubt that is what is causing the problem.

Comment: If the problem isn't clear, you should refrain from answering. OP needs the content-disposition header, and the Content-Type header's value is case-insensitive. Use comments to ask for clarification instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have had similar issues in the past, I would try setting the response content length explicitly.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", buffer.Length.ToString())
```